# How do you modify object in array with response from observable RxJs

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, rxjs

I am trying to iterate over an array of people and call an api which returns a new age which I will override the age and then merge with dogs array. The code looks like this:

```
const dogs = [{name:'Chichi', age:2}, {name:'Yayo', age:4}];
const people = [{name:'Mike', age:23}, {name:'John', age:45}];

const modifiedPeople = people.map(person => {        
    getNewAge(person).pipe(map(newAge=> {return person.age = newAge}));

return [...dogs, modifiedPeople];

})
```

This always returns an empty `modifiedPeople`. How can I perform this operation with RxJs in ES6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant call the async call in the `Array.map` as it is a synchronous method. It will not wait for async call to complete and moves further which is why you are getting undefined for `modifiedPeople` and moreover `pipe` operator returns an `Observable` which needs to be subscribed for the result.

```js
forkJoin(
  people.map(person =>
    this.getNewAge(person)
      .pipe(map(newAge => ({ ...person, age: newAge })))
  )
)
.subscribe(result => console.log(result));
```

the result will be your `modifiedPeople`